# Finding a fair on-duty rotation of multiple people

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, discrete-optimization

If you have N people and M of them need to be on duty at a time, what is an algorithm for generating a fair duty rotation?

"Fair" is subjective, so here is the definition I'm using:

- Every M-subset should be represented exactly once in the schedule
- The variance of time off-duty should be minimized

I'm interested in M=2 specifically, but I'm curious if there is a general approach as well.

For example, for N=4, M=2, I think this is an optimal schedule

```
1  2  3  4  5  6
A  A  B  A  B  C
B  C  D  D  C  D
```

because everyone has the same spans of time on- and off-duty except for B who gets the more consistent schedule of 1-on, 1-off. That's more fair than this schedule

```
1  2  3  4  5  6
A  A  A  B  B  C
B  C  D  C  D  D
```

where A is 3-on, 3-off while C is 1-on, 1-off. I'm using variance for fairness because even if (somehow) everyone had a 3-on, 3-off schedule, that would be "less fair" than everyone having a 1-on, 1-off schedule. Variance across all off-duty periods should be considered.